# Damaging inanimate objects in battles to indirectly gain advantage in battles

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, objects

1. I was thinking of using Spell damage to knockdown a dead Tree trunk in order for it to land on two/three skeletons and therefore pinning them effectively in place.
2. Assuming having 1 Torch lit only with an all-human party (and I am Chaotic Evil), I was thinking of aiming my spell on the Torch effectively putting it out and make my quick getaway.

Are these possible scenarios?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. Which game (and edition) are you asking about?

Comment: Which spell did you want to use?

Comment: These seems like two separate, but very answerable questions.  1) Can a character use spell damage to knock down a tree in order to pin opponents (e.g. skeletons) under it?  2) can a character use a spell damage to snuff a torch?  I suggest asking the first question on it's own.  So, just remove the 2nd case and reword the title.

Answer (score 2):

**Of course you can damage objects in battle.**  There aren't very many rules about it, but DMs can easily rule on such things.  There are HP values for common items in the DMG.  Things to note include:

- Many spells will not do damage to objects
- it's probably harder to hit a torch than you think
- dropping things on mobs isn't an automatic win (and anything you can do they can do as well)
- the Rule of Cool can be used to maximum effect doing these kinds of things.  Go for it!